# Should one close questions as duplicates of closed questions?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, duplicates, closed-questions

I have seen many questions in the past which are off-topic, and the community recognizes them as such, and it closes them as duplicates of the question when it was first asked and closed as off-topic. So should one close an off-topic question against another off-topic question which has been closed for being off-topic? Or should one simply close it as off-topic? And should one avoid creating duplicate chains of off-topic questions that lead to questions closed as off-topic (as this may confuse people and make them think that the question is on-topic as they may not go far enough down the duplicate chain to get to the question which was closed as off-topic)?

**Please also note** that although in my example I have talked about off-topic questions, I have seen the same done with questions with other close reasons (such as too broad, unclear, and primarily opinion-based). And am asking about them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Simply close the question for *its own* reasons. Close voting as dupe is *much* more work (for reviewers) and completely unnecessary if the question is clearly "close-valid".

I would save the duplicate- mark only for *good* questions that were asked before. As mentioned, closing as a dupe needs a lot of reviewers' time (that is: if you do it right), since *both* questions need to be read carefully.